# Picker list updated back-end but not front-end in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, binding, picker

I'm trying to update the list that is bound to a picker in xamarin forms. After I changed the content, the property is correctly set but it is not updated visually.

```
   public List<string> Types
        {
            get { return _types; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _types, value);
            }
        }

   pckTypes = new Picker() { ItemsSource = Model.Types, Title = "--Choose a type" };
```

Comment: how are you updating - are you assigning a new value to Types, or just adding/removing elements from the list?

Comment: I add it:  _list.Add(item.Value.Display);
Then I set Types=_list

Comment: it would be more efficient to use ObservableCollection instead of LIst and to just add directly to Types.  Does Model implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: I fixed it. What I did was Types=updateList. What I changed is using an foreach with Types.add(item) and now it works.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JaDa-ma - given that you've fixed it, please add an answer below showing the code that works. (Right now this question has no answer, so people trying to help will still come here, not realizing your problem is solved.)

Comment: This worked for me:

 `ObservableCollection<TypeEvent> _dataList = await service.GetAllTypesAsync();   foreach (var item in _dataList) { Types.Add(item); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me and solved my problem:

```
ObservableCollection<TypeEvent> _dataList = await service.GetAllTypesAsync();   
foreach (var item in _dataList) 
{ 
   Types.Add(item); 
}
```